# how to get element from json_encode array response - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a response from my code which looks like this

**Controller**

```
   $results = $response 
   echo $result->item;
   exit;
```

**Response**

```
{"item":"Samsung A","location":"Hamburg Avenue 5920"}
```

I want to get only item from the response..How do i achieve this ? The response is json encoded

Comment: Is there a typo in the controller code you posted? You've got both `$results` and `$result` variables. And if you're calling `exit` after echoing from the wrong variable, are you currently seeing any output at all? It's not very clear what the code is currently doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert json to object, and after that you can get the element:

```
$respObject = json_decode($response);
echo $respObject->item;
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **json_decode** the result  will converted into array

```
$results = json_decode($response); 
print_r( $results);
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

[json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function will helps.

```
$json_data = '{"item":"Samsung A","location":"Hamburg Avenue 5920"}';
$result = json_decode($json_data); 
echo $result->item;
```